cryptographic errors seen when using FIPS enabled OS with AO Availability Group
I'm looking for some help here to figure out the problem I'm facing with AOAG and FIPS enabled OS.
SqlServer version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU15-GDR) (KB5046059) - 16.0.4150.1 (X64)
        Sep 25 2024 17:34:41
        Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
        Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.1 (Plow)) <X64>

FIPS
# cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
1

Container Image https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/mssql/rhel/server/61f2f612f385723914ed60bc?q=sql%20server&image=64d5cb50ded7110343be3581&container-tabs=gti
I'm following the steps here deploy AOAG solution in two containers.
When I reach the point where I need to create the CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP I get the error below (see in the sqlserver errorlog)
2024-11-11 11:25:20.92 spid96      Always On: The local replica of availability group 'AG1' is preparing to transition to the primary role. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-11-11 11:25:20.94 spid96      The state of the local availability replica in availability group 'AG1' has changed from 'RESOLVING_NORMAL' to 'PRIMARY_PENDING'.  The state changed because the availability group is coming online.  For more information, see the SQL Server error log or cluster log.  If this is a Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) availability group, you can also see the WSFC management console.
2024-11-11 11:25:20.94 Server      The state of the local availability replica in availability group 'AG1' has changed from 'PRIMARY_PENDING' to 'PRIMARY_NORMAL'.  The state changed because the local replica has completed processing Online command from Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC).  For more information, see the SQL Server error log or cluster log.  If this is a Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) availability group, you can also see the WSFC management console.
2024-11-11 11:25:20.96 Server      Error: 9650, Severity: 16, State: 112.
2024-11-11 11:25:20.96 Server      A system cryptographic call failed during a Service Broker or Database Mirroring operation: system error '0xc0000001(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100)'.
2024-11-11 11:25:25.10 spid10s     Error: 9650, Severity: 16, State: 112.
2024-11-11 11:25:25.10 spid10s     A system cryptographic call failed during a Service Broker or Database Mirroring operation: system error '0xc0000001(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)'.
2024-11-11 11:25:30.10 spid10s     Error: 9650, Severity: 16, State: 112.
2024-11-11 11:25:30.10 spid10s     A system cryptographic call failed during a Service Broker or Database Mirroring operation: system error '0xc0000001(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)'.
2024-11-11 11:25:30.96 spid12s     A connection timeout has occurred while attempting to establish a connection to availability replica 'db2' with id [50FC95B8-0CB5-4DED-BC53-3186A510FBD3]. Either a networking or firewall issue exists, or the endpoint address provided for the replica is not the database mirroring endpoint of the host server instance.
2024-11-11 11:25:35.09 spid14s     Error: 9650, Severity: 16, State: 112.
2024-11-11 11:25:35.09 spid14s     A system cryptographic call failed during a Service Broker or Database Mirroring operation: system error '0xc0000001(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)'.

On secondary sqlserver instance the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROP JOIN command will timeout.
I tried to deploy the same container images in the Openshift Cluster with FIPS disabled and it worked perfectly fine !!!
So, I suspect the problem is related to FIPS not liked by SQLServer running in Linux. I even disabled encryption in the ENDPOINT, and also did not created the CERTIFICATE. However, I still seeing the same error messages when creating the AOAG.
Any help will be appreciated.
